# Generate expression using C++ boost::spirit PEG grammar

Tags: c++, expression-trees, boost-spirit, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm very new to C++ & boost::spirit. Trying to learn both by building a simple expression tree with only || and && using a PEG. I have built many parts of the code from the mini-xml tutorial in the docs.

Here is the [code](https://gist.github.com/868550), it works for simple strings like "1 || 0", "1 && 0", "1 || 1 && 0" ... but fails for "(1 || 1)". I don't quite understand why its failing to print, even though it says parse successful.

Also please guide me further on how I can make this code more intuitive and maintainable in the long run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enabling Spirit debug support will help:

a) add a define

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_QI_DEBUG
```

and b) add inside the constructor of your grammar a

```
BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(r);
```

for all rules (here `r`). As a result the parsers will print an execution tree at runtime showing you what rules are executed with what input and which attribute values have been filled (see [here](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/doc-addendum/debugging/) for more details).

As a general note (and this might not apply for you as you seem to try building an AST), Spirit's parsers are fully attributed. That means often you don't need any semantic actions to handle the attributes (see [here](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/attribute_handling/the-magical-power-of-attributes-in-spirit-primitives/), [here](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/attribute_handling/the-magical-power-of-attributes-in-spirit-operators/), and [here](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/attribute_handling/the-magical-power-of-attributes-in-spirit-directives-and-non-terminals/) for a consise introduction).

Comment: Thanks @hkaiser! The debug node really helped, I was able to resolve my bug (updated the gist). The problem was with my limited understanding of pointers, the grammar worked nicely (debug mode confirmed that).

Comment: how can I group my semantic actions into one boost::phoenix function? Currently I'm doing it like so: [at_c<1>(_val) = new_<E>()][*(at_c<1>(_val)) = _1] [at_c<2>(_val) = true]. This is working but if I try [1,2,3] it only considers 3 (ignores 1 and 2).

Comment: @na_ka_na: if only the last element of your comma delimited expression sequence is executed then you're missing the proper Phoenix header file defining the comma operator overload. It's #include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_statement.hpp>, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your particular Spirit code isn't working, but given that you are "very new to C++" and asking for how to make your code more maintainable in the long run, my answer is this:

Don't use Boost Spirit.  Use a well-understood parser generator like ANTLR (v2 can generate C++ code; v3 does not, so use v2), or lex & yacc or similar.

Boost Spirit is a great tool for demonstrating how far one can take certain features of C++.  It does not particularly help you if your goal is intuitive and maintainable code, especially if you are not already expert in C++ (this is no knock against you at all).

Comment: I am looking for ways to dive into C++, so I thought boost library might be a good place to start, (wrongly?) assuming it is wide spread. I'll try ANTLR too. My new workplace forces me to use C++ for certain tasks hence the maintainable requirement. Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: Spirit/Qi are some of the hardest parts of Boost to understand; Boost is one of the hardest (collections of) C++ libraries to understand; C++ is one of the more difficult languages for newcomers to understand.  You have chosen a tremendously difficult path.  :)  I have tried in two completely different projects in two completely different companies to use Boost Spirit in production code, and each time I gave up after a couple days.  I'm not the best C++ programmer, but I'm better at it than you are at this early stage, so I urge you to find some other C++-related things to cut your teeth on.

Comment: As for being wide spread, Boost is; Spirit is not.  Parts of Boost that see a lot more use are Unordered, Smart Pointers, Regex, Intrusive, Variant, Bind, Filesystem, Program Options, and Thread.